# nyc npm run test problem with spaces in the path

Tags: node.js

When I try to run "npm run coverage" or "nyc npm run test" it fails with the following error:

'C:\Users\First' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Assuming the right folder is under C:\Users\First Name\

The project was initially under the Documents folder but moved to a folder without spaces in the path under C:\project.

The npm folder was changed from appdata (under user's folder) to a folder without spaces under c:. PATH variables updated, pc restarted and still getting this issue.

If I run npc run test it runs perfectly fine, is nyc which is causing the issue.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options found to fix this issue:

- Rename the user folder. This requires a lot of changes in the registry and a long process.
- Create a new user with no spaces in the name and migrate everything and start using that user. This requires a lot of work as a lot of info is used on the current user.
- Create a new user with no spaces and only use this user with runas to run powershell or the command prompt used to run "npm run coverage" or "nyc npm run test".

Finally went for the last solutoin and now I can properly run the command without issues.

Is not the best solution as this only fixes the issue I'm having but doesn't fix the origin of it but at least is a workaround that allows me to keep working.

Regards.