# The system cannot find the path specified. Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1

Tags: npm, create-react-app

The following command:

```
C:\Users\Sahil raj\Desktop\r>npx create-react-app h
```

failed with the following error message

> The system cannot find the path specified. Install for [
> 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1

Comment: You have a space in your user name. This seems to be a problem. Similar questions: [nyc npm run test problem with spaces in the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52221395/nyc-npm-run-test-problem-with-spaces-in-the-path) and [Spaces in PATH npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871452/spaces-in-path-npm).